# What is the point of "Share name" in printer properties if Windows won't use it? AD environment

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012

So I set up all my printers in Windows Server 2012 Print Management.

The printers have "internal" names like `cdq.brother.mfc-8880` and `mtp.hp.lmnop.123`. But I gave them user-friendly share names like `Main Office Printer` and `Warehouse Printer`.

Of course when the client Windows 8 machines load their group policy, they show up as `cdq.brother.mfc-8880 on cdq.server.abcd1234`

My users have no idea what those names mean, and this makes the share names useless.

Answer (score 0):

The following Technet article may help you. Here are the steps it outlines:

1. Unshared the printer.
2. Restart the print spooler service in Local DC and Print Server.
3. Opened ADSI delete the printer.
4. Forced the replication
5. In one of the dc the print spooler service was not running, started that.
6. Published the printer in AD
7. Restart the print spooler service in Local DC and Print Server.
8. Forced the replication
9. Opened ADSI edit and now printer share name has appeared as an attribute.
10. Now from the Advance search option the printer is searchable. J

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/1b675ffc-0ba9-4d75-a009-d2f5b80c8010/printers-not-appearing-in-active-directory-search-by-shared-name?forum=winserverDS